# How to create proper classes hierarchy c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I need to create 2 classes: **Course** with following fields *name*, *teacher surname* and **Lecture** with *date*, *topic* and *present students amount*.

Then I should get next info: "Lecture with minimum students present", "List of topics with a specific word in their names", "Last letter of teacher surname".

I think that I just need an array of Lecture in my Course class, cuz I don't see any place for inheritance here. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Below is the way I wrote it.

```
#include <string>

class Course
{
private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_teacher_surname;
    Lecture *m_lectures;
};

class Lecture
{
private:
    std::string m_date;
    std::string m_topic;
    int m_present_students;
};
```

Comment: Replace `Lecture *m_lectures;` with `std::vector<Lecture> m_lectures;`.

Comment: If the instructions don't say that a course has a "lectures" member, it probably shouldn't.

Comment: We are not allowed to use data structers from the box

Comment: You are using `std::string`, this is like a vector of chars with even more member functions.

Comment: How can you tell how many `Lecture`s you have in a `Course`?

Comment: Don't worry about the lack of inheritance, object oriented doesn't mean "use inheritance for everything" . Far from it, best OO code uses aggregation for code reuse and only uses inheritance for real "derived class IS a base class" (lookup the Liskov substitution principle)

Comment: we cannot tell you if your approach matches with what you are expected to do for your homework. Even if you'd tell us the exact text and requirements of the exercise, we don't know what you covered in class and what your lecturer can expect you to use in a homework. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, specifically note the

Comment: I second Pepijn. Inheritance != object orientiation. You can write clean object oriented code without ever using inheritance. With few exceptions the standard library is the best example of that.

Comment: I think that 1) there is some context that you're not showing that you should be showing, and 2) you're making some assumptions about this exercise that you shouldn't be making.